# Basic PHPExcel output Excel File

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel and executed their sample code as displayed on the website:  https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Home

However, I can see the codes running well because I see this "message"

10:50:52 Create new PHPExcel object 10:50:52 Set properties 10:50:52 Add some data 10:50:52 Rename sheet 10:50:52 Write to Excel2007 format 10:50:52 Done writing file.

But I wasn't given an option to download any file?  How do I trigger them to ask me to download the file?

Comment: What is the code to trigger a download?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at some of the examples in the `/Examples` folder of the distribution or in the github repo, you'll find a number of examples with names like `01simple-download-xls.php` or `01simple-download-xlsx.php` that demonstrate how to send a generated Excel file to the browser.

It's also a good idea to read the documentation, which also explains how to do this, e.g. section `4.6.40` of the developer documentation, entitled `Redirect output to a client’s web browser`.

Answer (score 0):

That code outputs some text to the browser and saves the Excel file to disk (`$objWriter->save`). At no point does it do anything which would trigger a download.

If you want to download the file you have two options:

1. Print a link to the file (after the call to `save`), e.g. `echo '<a href="' . str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__) . '">Download Excel file</a>';`. You can then click this link to download the file.
2. Comment out the existing `echo` statements and add at the bottom of the script: `echo file_get_contents(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));`. This will output the contents of the file to the browser and should give you the option to download the file or to open it in Excel (or LibreOffice or whatever program you have registered for Excel files).

Also bear in mind that this example was written in 2007 and so may not work with the latest PHPExcel version.